# Finding best weight value for smooth constrained least squares with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels, least-squares

I have a least squares problem to solve without any known estimates of a parameter. I impose the constraint that my desired solution be smooth (the model parameters vary slowly), so I minimize the difference between adjacent parameters (a traditional remedy used for this geological problem).

The constraints are implemented by arranging the constraining equations as rows in the original data equation d = Gm. The auxiliary parameter w is chosen by trial and error (w is called Lagrange multiplier by some textbooks).

I have the following:

```
G = np.array([[1,0,1,0,0,6],
             [1,0,0,1,0,6.708],
             [1,0,0,0,1,8.485],
             [0,1,1,0,0,7.616],
             [0,1,0,1,0,7],
             [0,1,0,0,1,7.616]])

d = np.array([[2.323],
             [2.543],
             [2.857],
             [2.64],
             [2.529],
             [2.553]])
```

Now adding a constraint of an arbitrary w-weighted smoothness (w = 0.01):

```
w = 0.01
G = np.array([[1,0,1,0,0,6],
                 [1,0,0,1,0,6.708],
                 [1,0,0,0,1,8.485],
                 [0,1,1,0,0,7.616],
                 [0,1,0,1,0,7],
                 [0,1,0,0,1,7.616],
                 [w,-w,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,w,-w,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,w,-w,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,w,-w,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,w,-w]])

d = np.array([[2.323],
             [2.543],
             [2.857],
             [2.64],
             [2.529],
             [2.553],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0]])
```

However, choosing a proper value for w seems to be a key step to constraint a good solution for the model parameters.

So my question is: with Python, is there a way I can loop over many calculated solutions with different values for w and choose the value that was used to achieve the solution with the best quality?

Comment: Could you please explain what you consider _**the solution with the best quality**_? Are you trying to optimize a function of  `w`, `G`, and `d`??

Comment: With "best quality" I believe that the improved behavior of the residuals may be used to select an optimal set of values for the sought parameters

Comment: What is the definition of _**improved behavior of residuals**_? Maybe you can provide an equation/function to optimize or give an example, so we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

In the presented solution I'll refer to G_0 as G without the additional constraint and similarly d_0 is d without the additional zeros. I'm also assuming you're reading G_0 and d_0 from somewhere and I'm referring them as known.

```
import numpy as np

def create_W(n_rows, w):
    W = -np.diagflat(np.ones(n_rows), 1)
    np.fill_diagonal(W, 1)
    return W

def solution_quality_metric(m):
    # this need to be implemented to determine what you mean by "best"

n_rows = 5
d_w = np.zeros(n_rows)

# choose range for w values for example w_min = 0, w_max = 1, dw = 0.01

best_m = -np.inf
best_w = w_min

for w in np.arange(w_min, w_max, dw):
    W = create_W(n_rows, w)

    G = np.concatenate([G_0, W], axis=0)
    d = np.concatenate([d_0, d_w])
    m = np.lstsq(G, d)

    if solution_quality_metric(m) > best_m:
        best_m = solution_quality_metric(m)
        best_w = w
```

This code will obviously not work as is since you didn't specify what you mean by "solution with the best quality". For this you'll need to implement the `solution_quality_metric` function